# EC2 Docker Consul clustering

Tags: amazon-ec2, docker, consul

I am sure that this answer is somewhere out there but I can not find or fix it after several tries. Here is the use-case :

1.> I have two ec2 instances belonging to the same VPC but having different security groups

2.> Both the security groups have 22,80 (for public) and All Traffic from all ports open for CIDR block 10.20.0.0/16

3.> The internal IP of the EC2 instances are 10.20.0.51 (server-1) and 10.20.0.202 (server-2)

4.> I am using these following commands to run two dockerized consul servers on them

```
server-1 : docker run -it -p 8400:8400 -p 8500:8500 -p 8600:53/udp -p 8301:8301 -p 8300:8300 -h node1 progrium/consul -server -advertise 10.20.0.51  -bootstrap-expect 2

server-2 : docker run -it -p 8400:8400 -p 8500:8500 -p 8600:53/udp -p 8301:8301 -p 8300:8300 --name node2 -h node2 progrium/consul -server -advertise 10.20.0.202 -join 10.20.0.51
```

5.> Both of them start and for one second they recognise each other and the election happens and the first node gets elected but soon after that server-2 starts saying "memberlist: Suspect node1 has failed, no acks received" and server-1 also says "memberlist: Suspect node2 has failed, no acks received"

This is what the logs look like for server-1

```
2016/01/04 19:18:35 [INFO] serf: EventMemberJoin: node2 10.20.0.202
    2016/01/04 19:18:35 [INFO] consul: adding server node2 (Addr: 10.20.0.202:8300) (DC: dc1)
    2016/01/04 19:18:35 [INFO] consul: Attempting bootstrap with nodes: [10.20.0.51:8300 10.20.0.202:8300]
    2016/01/04 19:18:35 [WARN] raft: Heartbeat timeout reached, starting election
    2016/01/04 19:18:35 [INFO] raft: Node at 10.20.0.51:8300 [Candidate] entering Candidate state
    2016/01/04 19:18:35 [WARN] raft: Remote peer 10.20.0.202:8300 does not have local node 10.20.0.51:8300 as a peer
    2016/01/04 19:18:35 [INFO] raft: Election won. Tally: 2
    2016/01/04 19:18:35 [INFO] raft: Node at 10.20.0.51:8300 [Leader] entering Leader state
    2016/01/04 19:18:35 [INFO] consul: cluster leadership acquired
    2016/01/04 19:18:35 [INFO] consul: New leader elected: node1
    2016/01/04 19:18:35 [INFO] raft: pipelining replication to peer 10.20.0.202:8300
    2016/01/04 19:18:35 [INFO] consul: member 'node1' joined, marking health alive
    2016/01/04 19:18:35 [INFO] consul: member 'node2' joined, marking health alive
    2016/01/04 19:18:37 [INFO] memberlist: Suspect node2 has failed, no acks received
    2016/01/04 19:18:37 [INFO] agent: Synced service 'consul'
    2016/01/04 19:18:39 [INFO] memberlist: Suspect node2 has failed, no acks received
    2016/01/04 19:18:41 [INFO] memberlist: Suspect node2 has failed, no acks received
    2016/01/04 19:18:42 [INFO] memberlist: Marking node2 as failed, suspect timeout reached
    2016/01/04 19:18:42 [INFO] serf: EventMemberFailed: node2 10.20.0.202
    2016/01/04 19:18:42 [INFO] consul: removing server node2 (Addr: 10.20.0.202:8300) (DC: dc1)
```

And for server -2

```
2016/01/04 19:18:10 [INFO] serf: EventMemberJoin: node2 10.20.0.202
    2016/01/04 19:18:10 [INFO] serf: EventMemberJoin: node2.dc1 10.20.0.202
    2016/01/04 19:18:10 [INFO] raft: Node at 10.20.0.202:8300 [Follower] entering Follower state
    2016/01/04 19:18:10 [INFO] agent: (LAN) joining: [10.20.0.51]
    2016/01/04 19:18:10 [INFO] consul: adding server node2 (Addr: 10.20.0.202:8300) (DC: dc1)
    2016/01/04 19:18:10 [INFO] consul: adding server node2.dc1 (Addr: 10.20.0.202:8300) (DC: dc1)
    2016/01/04 19:18:10 [INFO] serf: EventMemberJoin: node1 10.20.0.51
    2016/01/04 19:18:10 [INFO] agent: (LAN) joined: 1 Err: <nil>
    2016/01/04 19:18:10 [ERR] agent: failed to sync remote state: No cluster leader
    2016/01/04 19:18:10 [INFO] consul: adding server node1 (Addr: 10.20.0.51:8300) (DC: dc1)
    2016/01/04 19:18:12 [INFO] memberlist: Suspect node1 has failed, no acks received
    2016/01/04 19:18:14 [INFO] memberlist: Suspect node1 has failed, no acks received
    2016/01/04 19:18:16 [INFO] memberlist: Suspect node1 has failed, no acks received
    2016/01/04 19:18:17 [INFO] memberlist: Marking node1 as failed, suspect timeout reached
    2016/01/04 19:18:17 [INFO] serf: EventMemberFailed: node1 10.20.0.51
    2016/01/04 19:18:17 [INFO] memberlist: Suspect node1 has failed, no acks received
    2016/01/04 19:18:17 [INFO] consul: removing server node1 (Addr: 10.20.0.51:8300) (DC: dc1)
    2016/01/04 19:18:19 [INFO] serf: EventMemberJoin: node1 10.20.0.51
    2016/01/04 19:18:19 [INFO] consul: adding server node1 (Addr: 10.20.0.51:8300) (DC: dc1)
    2016/01/04 19:18:19 [INFO] consul: New leader elected: node1
    2016/01/04 19:18:21 [INFO] memberlist: Suspect node1 has failed, no acks received
    2016/01/04 19:18:22 [INFO] agent: Synced service 'consul'
    2016/01/04 19:18:23 [INFO] memberlist: Suspect node1 has failed, no acks received
    2016/01/04 19:18:25 [INFO] memberlist: Suspect node1 has failed, no acks received
    2016/01/04 19:18:26 [INFO] memberlist: Marking node1 as failed, suspect timeout reached
    2016/01/04 19:18:26 [INFO] serf: EventMemberFailed: node1 10.20.0.51
    2016/01/04 19:18:26 [INFO] consul: removing server node1 (Addr: 10.20.0.51:8300) (DC: dc1)
    2016/01/04 19:18:26 [INFO] memberlist: Suspect node1 has failed, no acks received
    2016/01/04 19:18:40 [INFO] serf: attempting reconnect to node1 10.20.0.51:8301
    2016/01/04 19:18:40 [INFO] serf: EventMemberJoin: node1 10.20.0.51
```

What exactly I am doing wrong. All I want is to run two consul docker in two EC2 instances and communicate between them without explicitly opening up the ports in the security group (When I explicitly open them up it works of course!)

Please can somebody help.

Thanks

Comment: Can you please show both security groups? Consul uses both TCP and UDP. If your first security group allows all of 10.20.0.0/16 but only on TCP it will not work.

Comment: Actually I have made a small change I have put both the servers under a single security group and allowed all TCP connections for port range 0 - 65535 and I mentioned to allow this traffic for 10.20.0.0/16 CIDR. It works fine!! :)